# Как получить ошибку используя 3 заголовка?

Tags: c, header, define

3 заголовка:

1. `core.h`

```c
#pragma once

#include "some.h"
#include "other.h"
```

2. `some.h`

```c
#pragma once

#include "core.h"

typedef int some_type;

#define some_call __stdcall

other_type other_call some_func();
```

3. `other.h`

```c
#pragma once

#include "core.h"

typedef float other_type;

#define other_call __cdecl

some_type some_call other_func();
```

---

Внутри файла `some.h` получаем ошибку, что не определены `some_type` и `some_call`. Как избавиться от этой ошибки (желательно без объединения файлов `some.h` и `other.h` в 1 файл).

---

Я специально упростил мою ситуацию до самого минимума.

Comment: Создать четвёртый хедер, для инициализации данных типов.

Comment: Избавиться от циклической зависимости. some зависит от core, который зависит от other, который зависит от core, который зависит от some... Как именно вы избавитесь - дело ваше, способов есть несколько...

Comment: @Harry я увидел 1 от AlexGlebe. Есть ли ещё более элегантные способы избежать зависимости?

Comment: Без другого хедера есть вариант поставить определения типов **перед** включениями других хедеров. Но это не очень красиво.

Comment: Правила простые, файл `some.h` зависит от этих типов, и `core.h` тоже зависит. Зависимости нужно определять **перед** использованием. А вы определяете **после** инклудов. Значит определять нужно перед инклудами или запихнуть как четвёртый файл **перед** ними.